# I am unable to install Wine due to issues with multiarch support. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Tags: wine, dependencies

I cant install wine. Cant do anything with this.

```
 sudo aptitude install wine1.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} 
  libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} 
  libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.1:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} 
  libdrm-intel1:i386{ab} libdrm-nouveau1a:i386{ab} libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} libdrm2:i386{ab} 
  libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} 
  libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgcrypt11:i386{a} libgd2-xpm:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{ab} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} 
  libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgnutls26:i386{a} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-2:i386{a} 
  libgphoto2-port0:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libice6:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} libjson0:i386{a} 
  libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} 
  libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms1:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.0:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libogg0:i386{a} 
  libopenal1:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} 
  libpam-winbind{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpng12-0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} 
  libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} 
  libselinux1:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{a} 
  libstdc++6:i386{ab} libtasn1-3:i386{a} libtiff4:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libusb-0.1-4:i386{a} 
  libuuid1:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} 
  libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} 
  libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} 
  libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} 
  libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} 
  libxrender1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxt6:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} ttf-umefont{a} 
  ttf-unfonts-core{a} unixodbc{a} winbind{a} wine-gecko1.9{a} wine-gecko1.9:i386{a} 
  wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.5 wine1.5-amd64{a} wine1.5-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} zlib1g:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 125 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 173 MB of archives. After unpacking 452 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 4.7.2-11precise2) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) but 4.7.2-11precise2 is installed.
 libdrm-radeon1 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 9.0-0ubuntu1) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3) but 9.0-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 9.0-0ubuntu1) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3) but 9.0-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 9.0-0ubuntu1) but 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.3) but 9.0-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed.
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libdrm-nouveau1a : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau1a (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libdrm-intel1 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1:i386 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1 (!= 2.4.39-0ubuntu0.1) but 2.4.39-0ubuntu1 is installed.
Internal error: the solver Install(wine1.5:i386 1.5.23-0ubuntu1 <wine1.5-amd64:amd64 1.5.23-0ubuntu1 -> {wine1.5:amd64 1.5.23-0ubuntu1 wine1.5:i386 1.5.23-0ubuntu1}>) of a supposedly unresolved dependency is already installed in step 18
Internal error: the solver Install(dpkg:amd64 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 <wine-gecko1.9:i386 1.9-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 -> {dpkg:amd64 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 dpkg:amd64 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 dpkg:i386 1.16.1.2ubuntu7 dpkg:i386 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1}>) of a supposedly unresolved dependency is already installed in step 411
open: 135; closed: 364; defer: 109; conflict: 202                                                    .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Keep the following packages at their current version:                     
1)       libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                  
2)       libasound2:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
3)       libasyncns0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
4)       libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
5)       libavahi-common3:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
6)       libc6:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
7)       libcapi20-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
8)       libcomerr2:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
9)       libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
10)      libdb5.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
11)      libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
12)      libdrm-intel1:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
13)      libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
14)      libdrm-radeon1:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
15)      libdrm2:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
16)      libexif12:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
17)      libexpat1:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
18)      libffi6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
19)      libflac8:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
20)      libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
21)      libfreetype6:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
22)      libgcc1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
23)      libgcrypt11:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
24)      libgd2-xpm:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
25)      libgif4:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
26)      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
27)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
28)      libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
29)      libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
30)      libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
31)      libgnutls26:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
32)      libgpg-error0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
33)      libgphoto2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
34)      libgphoto2-port0:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
35)      libgpm2:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
36)      libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
37)      libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
38)      libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 [Not Installed]                    
39)      libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
40)      libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                
41)      libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                               
42)      libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                               
43)      libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
44)      libice6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
45)      libieee1284-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
46)      libjpeg-turbo8:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
47)      libjpeg8:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
48)      libjson0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
49)      libk5crypto3:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
50)      libkeyutils1:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
51)      libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
52)      libkrb5-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
53)      libkrb5support0:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
54)      liblcms1:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
55)      libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
56)      libllvm3.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
57)      libltdl7:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
58)      libmpg123-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
59)      libncurses5:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
60)      libogg0:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
61)      libopenal1:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
62)      liborc-0.4-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
63)      libosmesa6:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
64)      libp11-kit0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
65)      libpciaccess0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
66)      libpcre3:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
67)      libpng12-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
68)      libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
69)      libroken18-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
70)      libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
71)      libsasl2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
72)      libsasl2-modules:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
73)      libselinux1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
74)      libsm6:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
75)      libsndfile1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
76)      libsqlite3-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
77)      libssl1.0.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
78)      libstdc++6:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
79)      libtasn1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
80)      libtiff4:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
81)      libtinfo5:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
82)      libusb-0.1-4:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
83)      libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
84)      libv4l-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
85)      libv4lconvert0:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
86)      libvorbis0a:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
87)      libvorbisenc2:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
88)      libwind0-heimdal:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
89)      libwrap0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
90)      libx11-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
91)      libx11-xcb1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
92)      libxau6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
93)      libxcb-glx0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
94)      libxcb1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
95)      libxcomposite1:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
96)      libxcursor1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
97)      libxdamage1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
98)      libxdmcp6:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
99)      libxext6:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
100)     libxfixes3:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
101)     libxi6:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
102)     libxinerama1:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
103)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
104)     libxpm4:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
105)     libxrandr2:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
106)     libxrender1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
107)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
108)     libxt6:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
109)     libxxf86vm1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
110)     wine-gecko1.9:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
111)     wine1.5 [Not Installed]                                                 
112)     wine1.5-amd64 [Not Installed]                                           
113)     wine1.5-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
114)     zlib1g:i386 [Not Installed]                                             

       Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                              
115)     libncurses5:i386 recommends libgpm2:i386                                
116)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 recommends libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)           
117)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends udev:i386 (>= 0.175)                       
118)     libgphoto2-2:i386 recommends libgphoto2-l10n:i386 (>= 2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2)
119)     winetricks recommends wine1.5 | wine1.4 | wine | cxoffice5 | cxgames5   
120)     wine-mono0.0.8 recommends wine1.5                                       
121)     wine-gecko1.9 recommends wine1.5-amd64                                  
122)     wine1.5-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386                               
123)     wine-gecko1.9:i386 recommends wine1.5-i386:i386                         


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: I don't think this is really a typical unmet dependencies problem. This seems like a combination of using `aptitude` where `apt-get` should be used (because the `aptitude` multiarch bug is only fixed in 12.10), and the proper software source for `wine1.5` not being enabled (see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/256049/22949) and its comments). I recommend we reopen this.

Comment: The contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and output of `apt-get update` would be useful. It looks like you have a combination of precise and quantal versions there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try installing Wine 1.5

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

That should get you up and running.

**References**

[Adding the WineHQ PPA Repository](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I aslo face similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04, I uses some step which i suggest here but before that you should try remove any instance of wine using following

1. use command to see list of particular package is installed
   `sudo dpkg --list | grep wine`

   it displayed list of preinstalled wine instance, if any
2. Remove the package which result in step first
   for e.g. if list like 
   `ii  wine1.5                                1.5.23-0ubuntu1                         Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)
   ii  wine1.5-i386                           1.5.23-0ubuntu1                         Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
   ii  winetricks`

use command following commnd to remove wine1.5, wine1.5-i386 as
`sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.5
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.5-i386` or `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*`

- to remove additional supporting file if not completely removed by purge command
  `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove wine1.5 and sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove wine1.5i386` && `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Referance:  [Read article for remove package](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstallremove-a-packagesoftwareprogram)

Try to add new architecture i386, use
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` &&`sudo apt-get update`

Add latest repositery of wine `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` &&`sudo apt-get update`
Finaly run `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Also check following link for similar solution....
[similar solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204840/dependency-error-while-installing-wine)
[Other Similar Problem Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234559/im-having-dependency-problems-with-wine-and-multiarch-on-12-04x64-i-need-a-sol)

Comment: wine is not installed. Architecture i386 added. PPA also added before. Not working. I tried ppa-purge, then re-added.

Answer (score 0):

[`aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html) has [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768) that keeps it from handling [multiarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) properly. So if you use [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) instead, that may fix the problem. (And of course make sure to `update` before performing any major package management action from the command-line, unless you've done so recently.)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

The bug [was fixed in Ubuntu 12.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768/comments/113), but it has not been fixed in 12.04 or 11.10.

### If `apt-get` says `wine1.5` is not available:

If you don't specifically need version 1.5 of Wine, just install the latest version available in the official Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

If you **do** specifically need Wine 1.5, and you're running Ubuntu 11.10 or later (which it appears you are), enable [the Wine PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

(Or you can use [this graphical method](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).)

Then you should be able to install Wine 1.5:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Please note that, after adding the PPA with `add-apt-repository`, you **must** run `sudo apt-get update` for the package manager to know to consult the newly added software source.

### If that doesn't work:

If it still says `Package wine1.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.`, then it will be necessary to gather more information on what software sources are available. So run these commands, then put the output (separately) in your question:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine1.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine1.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine1.5' has no installation candidate

Comment: @g1ra I've expanded my answer; please let me know if it helps (or if not, what happens).